# How is one able to separate exactly one tenth of an income for maaser?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

[This article](https://images.shulcloud.com/291/uploads/Announcements/2017/Adopt-A-Kollel-Newsletter/Vayeitzei--Maaser.pdf) says:

> According to some authorities, the special virtue of maaser—for
> which the Torah promises wealth (and even permits “testing”
> Hashem)—is limited to donating exactly one tenth of one’s
> income. Therefore, even a person who gives more than 10% of
> his income to charity, should preferably separate exactly 10%
> first, and then give the extra moneys (Shut Chavos Ya’ir 234,
> based on Mishna in [Avos 1:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Here is my question: if you're paid in an even amount of money, such as 1,000 or 650, great, you can give 10% pretty easily. But let's say you get paid and it comes out to cents? such as 650.78. 10% of such a number is not possible to give (i.e., the closest possible would be 65.07 or 65.08  but you cannot give 65.078! What should you do?

Comment: here are some ideas - you do not have to give it right away, wait and do it every 2 checks. You could buy something and donate the percentage of the object that represents the 10% and keep the rest for yourself for 1 minute, then donate the rest afterwards.

Comment: You shouldn't ask the community, you should ask the author of that article. In articles like that, they often use words without really meaning them and people like you take it unfortunately very seriously.

Comment: The smallest amount of money dealt with in halacha is the prutah. Presumably as long as it is accurate to within a prutah, it is exact. In my yeshiva, a prutah was considered ten cents.

Comment: Just a thought, does the amount have to be given as a 'Maaser amount', or do you just need to know what it is? As in, can you give a $72 check to an organization, but know that 65.078 of it is 'actual Maaser', with the rest being extra.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Rabbeinu Yonah clearly limits the testing of Hashem to actual tithes from produce, and not ma'aser kesafim which is not d'oraisa.